# Pivoting Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in sql server created using this code

```
CREATE TABLE t3
(`NAME` varchar(20), `VALUE` varchar(17));

INSERT INTO t3
(`NAME`, `VALUE`)
VALUES
('Name_Screened', 'johny bravo'),
('Name_Screened', 'JOHNY CHAVO'),
('Match_Type', 'Direct'),
('Match_Type', 'Direct'),
('Disposition', 'Successful'),
('Disposition', 'Successful'),
('Compliance_Approval', 'Yes'),
('Compliance_Approval', 'Yes'),
('Supporting_Documents', 'Lexix Nexis Match'),
('Supporting_Documents', 'WORD NET MATCH');
```

I am trying to pivot this data using the code

```
SELECT  PVT.Match_Type,  PVT.Name_Screened,PVT.Disposition,PVT.Compliance_Approval,PVT.Supporting_Documents
FROM T3 
PIVOT (
 max(VALUE)
FOR NAME IN    (Match_Type,Name_Screened,Disposition,Compliance_Approval,Supporting_Documents)
) PVT
```

but i am only getting one row like this

```
Match_Type - Name_Screened - Disposition - Compliance_Approval - Supporting_Documents
Direct     - JOHNY CHAVO   - Successful  - Yes                 - WORD NET MATCH
```

i want two rows from the 10 data rows but get only one 
I think i am missing out on right aggregation function in pivot only. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to slightly modify your query:

```
SELECT PVT.Match_Type, PVT.Name_Screened, PVT.Disposition, 
       PVT.Compliance_Approval,PVT.Supporting_Documents
FROM (
   SELECT NAME, VALUE, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY VALUE) AS rn
   FROM T3 ) AS src
PIVOT (
   MAX(VALUE)
   FOR NAME IN (Match_Type, Name_Screened, Disposition, 
                Compliance_Approval,Supporting_Documents)
) pvt
```

This will produce a separate row for each `rn` value of `src`.

Comment: thank you so much . The moment i get 15 reputation i will vote this up.

Comment: An Update if you dont want to lose the order of your data and to stop getting it mixed with the other rows add an ID field to the original table(in my case T3) then use  ORDER BY ID instead of ORDER BY VALUE in OVER. what do u say @giorgos

Comment: @AashishKumar This new `ID` column could take the place of the calculated `rn` field. In this sense you are right: by adding `ID` you can explicitly define ordering and hence not rely on `VALUE`.